# Rebuilding the AddressBook example in protobuf-csharp-port 2.4.1.473

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I have sucessfully built the example AddressBook project in protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.473-source and have even got it to work with the C++ example from the protobuf-2.4.1-win32. However, when I try to regenerate the AddressBookProtos.cs file and execute it, I encounter the following runtime problem.

```
Options:
L: List contents
A: Add new person
Q: Quit
Action? a
Exception executing action: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer
for 'Google.ProtocolBuffers.Examples.AddressBook.AddressBook' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer
for 'Google.ProtocolBuffers.Examples.AddressBook.AddressBookProtos' threw an exception. --->
System.ArgumentException: Invalid embedded descriptor for "tutorial/addressbook.proto". --->
Google.ProtocolBuffers.Descriptors.DescriptorValidationException: tutorial/addressbook.proto:
Dependencies passed to FileDescriptor.BuildFrom() don't match those listed in the
FileDescriptorProto.
at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.BuildFrom(FileDescriptorProto proto,
FileDescriptor[] dependencies)
at Google.ProtocolBuffers.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.InternalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Byte[]
descriptorData, FileDescriptor[] dependencies, InternalDescriptorAssigner descriptorAssigner)
```

I tried to generate the AddressBookProtos.cs from protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.473-release-binaries, using protos\tutorial\addressbook.proto but it seems to be missing the namespace and umbrella_classname options. Also, the version numbers listed in src\AddressBook\AddressBookProtos.cs that came in protobuf-csharp-port-2.4.1.473-source says it is "2.3.0.277".

Comment: It looks we haven't regenerated those in a while, and have introduced bugs along the way. Could you file an issue on the project page, and I'll look at it when I get the chance? Please include exactly how you regenerated the C# file.

Comment: As requested, issue opened [link](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/issues/detail?id=47). 

I found that if I generate AddressBookProto.cs in protoc\ then AddressBook.exe works. The problem occurs only when I use protogen.exe in Release\v4.0. What is the purpose of the two locations?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure - that's interesting. Will look at it when I get some time.